# youtube-dl removed but still there

Tags: linux, bash, apt, apt-get, youtube-dl

There's a ghost in the shell.

I tried to remove youtube-dl through `brew uninstall youtube-dl`:

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

cool, that means I have not even installed brew.

I then checked if I could uninstall it through `sudo pip uninstall youtube-dl`:

```
Skipping youtube-dl as it is not installed.
```

Let's check also `sudo pip3 uninstall youtube-dl`:

```
Skipping youtube-dl as it is not installed.
```

Let's confirm it has not been installed through apt with `sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'youtube-dl' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But if I type `youtube-dl --version` youtube-dl is still there:

```
2021.04.26
```

I post a picture to show that I'm not mad:

[image]

If I type `whereis youtube-dl` the response is:

```
youtube-dl: /home/bobby/.local/bin/youtube-dl
```

So I know it's there but how can I remove it?

What the hack of an application installed it?

**EDIT:** thank you but if I look inside the youtube-dl file I see this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from youtube_dl import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

So this is not the youtube-dl executable but it looks like it's calling other files somewhere. Where are them?

Comment: Isn't brew a tool for macOS? Why would you try to use it on a Linux distro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you installed it ? You may have installed it manually. The package system does not know about it. So in that case delete the executable manually.

```
rm /home/bobby/.local/bin/youtube-dl
```

**EDIT:** Ok but still delete this file please, lets try to view all pip packages `pip list -v`
Find the path to the modules folder: something like `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` or `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

and search for the `youtube-dl` to delete, if you still cant find it;  try to install the package again throu `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` or `pip install youtube-dl`

If still no success. You can search for the whole system: `sudo find / -name youtube-dl` or `sudo find / -type f -name "youtube*"`

Comment: thank you @warfish, I added more info

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani i edited my answer :)

Comment: `rm` and `pip install youtube-dl`. I'm now on the latest youtube-dl version. Thanks